# Azure IotHub to Spark Structure Streaming to COSMOS DB (with and wo Kafka)

Tags: spark-streaming, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub

1. For the first scenario, I want to use Spark Structured Streaming with Iot Hub in entrance and Cosmos DB in output. I have used the following connectors:

   - azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.2
   - azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.2.0 (not directly with Maven, by import uber jar

The fact is, when I tried to import my data to Cosmos DB, I receveid the following error :

> "java.lang.assertionError : Assertion failed : received sequence number 1790 doesn’t match request sequence number 1791"

2. With Kafka : I tried another solution, using Iot Hub and Kafka, for using Kafka as sourcing in Spark Structured Streaming (instead of Event Hub connector). But after all the configuration about Kafka, I have the following error:

> “Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.microsoft.azure.iot.kafka.connect.source.IotHubSourceConnector”.

There is a problem with the alias name.
Do you think this is belong to the fact that we are using Iot Hub instead of Event hub ?

=> I will try a third solution, that is using Stream Analytics to push into Cosmos DB, then implement a Cosmos DB Change Feed, to use it in Spark Structured Streaming as an entrance. Hope this gonna work.

Any advice on the 2 above scenario are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario: you may want to try version 2.3.4 (azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.4) that should fix that specific problem, as stated here from the Dev Team:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/313

and here

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/pull/384

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with @Tidjoe, and now the solution is working.

That's the connector we are using:

- azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.4
- azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.2.0 (not directly with Maven, by import uber jar

Our solution is working with Eventhub or IotHub in entrance.

Thank you for the release !